# is 'worthful' a word?

Tags: word-meaning, dictionaries

Though I have heard 'worthful' in some usages and also I have checked it in the [Meriam-Webster website](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worthful), I am still in doubt if it is a formal word, because lots of the grammar checkers show it as wrong (even this web site spell-checker!)

Comment: It may be a word, but unless you are trying to jam it into a poem/rap so that it rhymes with something I would use "worthy" in common speech and writing.

Comment: Why "worthful" when you can say "worthy"?

Comment: @MARamezani I would like to know if it is a correct word or not; because I see it in my life-days.

Comment: Kevin's answer is my suggestion. Still, the question I asked was rhetorical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is a word.  However, it is [seldom used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worthful%2C%20worthy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworthful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworthy%3B%2Cc0).  I would avoid it and use "worthy" instead.

Answer (score 1):

To use "worthful" as a substitute for 'worthy' or 'worthwhile' does not sound right. It was pointed out that it might be ok to use it to fit into a poem for rhyming purpose. So I believe that it is next to, not being an actual word.

Similar notion may be right in case of "momentarily", meaning, for a short while. However "momentarily" is being used by American Broadcasters to say 'in a short while', which does not sound right.